# Java: The logic of the conditional statement doesn't work and allows the program to run even when the conditions are not met

Tags: java, conditional-statements, numberformatexception

I have the following two lines of code, where I have set certain conditions for a conditional statement to execute. However, there is something wrong with the logic, because the program inside the conditional runs even when the conditions are not met.

```
if (!(token.equals('+')) && !(token.equals('-')) && !(token.equals('*')) && !(token.equals('/'))) {
            operandStack.push(Integer.valueOf(token));
        }
```

I am getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "whatever operator (+,-,* and /) that I enter in my test case" in the second line of this code and I realize that it's because Integer.valueOf() doesn't work for symbols, but that's the thing. If it's a symbol, it shouldn't be executing in the first place. I have tried looking for all kinds of typos or stupid syntax mistakes, but haven't found any. What's wrong with this logic?

Comment: What is `token`?  I have a hunch that it's a `String`.

Comment: Is `token` a string? You are comparing it to `char` values.

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes with double quotes instead

Comment: @ Blorgbeard Yes, token is a String. I am not sure I understand. How are '+', '-', '/' etc. NOT String values?

Comment: `"+"` is a `String`, `'+'` is a `char` (and they will never be equal).

Comment: @vikarjramun Already tried that

Comment: @azurefrog Oh I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might do better to check if the token is an integer via a regular expression:

```
if (token.matches("\\d+")) {
    operandStack.push(Integer.parseInt(token));
}
```

And then parse the string into an integer.

The pattern `\d+` (double escaped for Java) matches on one or more digits.